# Comparing string by view similarity or transliteration

Tags: c#

I need to deduplicate relatively big list of comapny names that comes from many different sources world wide.

My main problem is characters that look same but has different char code e.g. latin 'ABCEHKOyTX' and cyrilic 'АВСЕНКОуТХ' etc.

I'm sure in other languages there is much more of them.

Strings normalization only helps to certen extent.

It would be also great if solution will also work for transliterations e.g. when latin name goes by the sound of original string e.g. my name Oleg vs. Олег.

Bonus: And super great if it will also work for combination of characters e.g. 'bl' and 'Ы'.

Comment: thats a wild problem. You could consider to turn it into an image and than use OCR software but i think that might rather hurt than help...

Comment: Yeah. I also think that I can't just do it 100% automatically, but what would also work, a solution that would find e.g. duplicate candidates rated by similarity.

Comment: Found this http://www.unicode.org/Public/security/latest/confusables.txt it might help! At least it contains my example with 'bl' and 'Ы'...